# Inner Join - Two Fields Pulling from One

Tags: ms-access

I have a database that has two columns in a table called "DISPOSITION_LOG" that pull data from the same source.

The two columns are "DIAGNOSTIC_CODE" and "DIAGNOSTIC_CODE_2".

During entry the user sees the diagnostic codes as text but when a record is saved it stores that data as the ID(PK) number from the "DIAGNOSTIC_CODES" table. I also do something similar with the "ACTION" and "RMA_OWNER" columns in the DISPOSITION_LOG" table.

When I export the data, I use an inner join to retrieve the the "RMA_OWNER" as well as "WARRANTY_TECH_ACTION", and have no issues.

When I added the first diagnostic code with an inner join, it worked fine. When I attempted to pull the data for the second one I hit a problem.

Here is the code that I used that works prior to the second diagnostic code being added.

```
SELECT DISPOSITION_LOG.ID,
DISPOSITION_LOG.SKU,
DISPOSITION_LOG.SERIAL_NUMBER,
DIAGNOSTIC_CODES.DIAGNOSTIC_CODE,
DISPOSITION.ACTION,
RMA_OWNERS.RMA_OWNER
FROM (((DISPOSITION_LOG
INNER JOIN RMA_OWNERS ON DISPOSITION_LOG.RMA_OWNER=RMA_OWNERS.ID)
INNER JOIN DISPOSITION ON DISPOSITION_LOG.WARRANTY_TECH_ACTION=DISPOSITION.ID)
INNER JOIN DIAGNOSTIC_CODES ON DISPOSITION_LOG.DIAGNOSTIC_CODE=DIAGNOSTIC_CODES.ID);
```

Here is one of my attempts at adding the second one. This attempt prints nothing out at all.

```
SELECT DISPOSITION_LOG.ID,
DISPOSITION_LOG.SKU,
DISPOSITION_LOG.SERIAL_NUMBER,
DIAGNOSTIC_CODES.DIAGNOSTIC_CODE AS DIAGNOSTIC_CODE,
DIAGNOSTIC_CODES.DIAGNOSTIC_CODE AS DIAGNOSTIC_CODE_2,
DISPOSITION.ACTION,
RMA_OWNERS.RMA_OWNER
FROM (((DISPOSITION_LOG
INNER JOIN RMA_OWNERS ON DISPOSITION_LOG.RMA_OWNER=RMA_OWNERS.ID)
INNER JOIN DISPOSITION ON DISPOSITION_LOG.WARRANTY_TECH_ACTION=DISPOSITION.ID)
INNER JOIN DIAGNOSTIC_CODES ON DISPOSITION_LOG.DIAGNOSTIC_CODE=DIAGNOSTIC_CODES.ID AND DISPOSITION_LOG.DIAGNOSTIC_CODE_2=DIAGNOSTIC_CODES.ID));
```

I have tried a couple of other things but no luck so far, I either get a join expression not supported message or nothing at all.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pulling a table more than once into a query should not be an issue. The first occurrence will have the actual table name, the second will have an alias like Diagnostic_Code_2. Your SQL is assigning alias to field, not table. The field name will be unchanged. Use Access query designer instead of trying to write this yourself in SQLView.

Comment: Correction, in your case the alias table name will be `DIAGNOSTIC_CODES_1`.

Comment: I tried using the query designer, what you suggested does not work. It asks for a parameter value for the secondary diagnostic code field. As an aside, I prefer to use the SQL design as I do not learn as much from using the query designer. Edit - You suggested Diagnostic_Code_2 was an alias, but it is not, the table column is named DIAGNOSTIC_CODE_2 as it shows in the above code I listed.

Comment: Yes, you have a field named DIAGNOSTIC_CODE_2 in DISPOSITION_LOG but alias name for second instance of DIAGNOSTIC_CODES table would be DIAGNOSTIC_CODES_1. I know it can work. I have done it many times. I use query builder to construct query then switch to SQLView to learn syntax. Drag DIAGNOSTIC_CODES table into query designer twice. Manually set links between fields.

Comment: Here is example from my db: `SELECT Games.*, Umpires.LastN, Umpires_1.LastN
FROM Umpires AS Umpires_1 INNER JOIN (Umpires INNER JOIN Games ON Umpires.UmpID = Games.Plate) ON Umpires_1.UmpID = Games.Base;`

Comment: You are correct, I tinkered with it before I completely understood what you were saying. I ended up getting it to work with your suggestion. Thank you for your help.